# ReportViewer no VS2017 bug

Tags: reportviewer

Estou usando o ReportViewer no Visual Studio 2017 para criar um relatório, e tudo vai bem até que eu inclua um parâmetro. Nesse momento, não sei por qual razão, a definição do relatório muda de:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

Para:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

Recebo o seguinte erro na hora de apresentar o relatório:

```
11:40:28 Error
The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not
11:40:28 Error
well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target
11:40:28 Error
namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.
```